# Error inserting TaskRelation records

Tags: tasks, clone, shared-activities, taskrelation

I have a client who wants the ability to clone a task that has multiple contacts.  They would make slight changes to the cloned task (Assigned To, etc) but the multiple contacts would remain the same.

I'm getting a DUPLICATE_VALUE error when I tried to insert the cloned TaskRelation records and I can't figure out why.  Do I need to create the task relation records in a different way?

Here's what I'm doing:

I retrieve the TaskRelation records for the original task, use the clone() list method, then insert the cloned Task, then replace the TaskId with the cloned task Id, and attempt to insert the cloned taskRelation records.

The error detail is:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: : []

Here are the code snippets:

```
originalRelations = [SELECT RelationId, TaskId, IsWhat FROM TaskRelation 
        WHERE TaskId = :originalTask.Id AND IsWhat = false];
// Don't preserve Id, deep clone.
cloneTask = originalTask.clone(false, true);
cloneRelations = originalRelations.deepClone(false);
...
...
insert cloneTask;
for (TaskRelation relation : cloneRelations) {
    relation.TaskId = cloneTask.Id;
}
insert cloneRelations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - when I insert the clone task, Salesforce automatically creates a TaskRelation for the WhoId, so the duplicate error is because my clone TaskRelation list also contains that combination of WhoId / TaskId.

When I construct the clone TaskRelation list in a loop and skip the existing Task.WhoId, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning is nothing but creating a new record which means you just need to add whoId or WhatId and you can not specify the id of new record while inserting.And if you want to keep track of from what task the current cloned task is generated you can create a custom field and populate it with the cloneTask.Id.

In this portion of code you are assigning the Id which is the reason for the error.I made it bold where you are making a mistake and adding a line of code. I am not sure when you were cloning whoId gets auto populted or not.
for (TaskRelation relation : cloneRelations) {
    **relation.TaskId = cloneTask.Id;**
}
insert cloneRelations;

Comment: Actually, the TaskRelation ID is already blank because of the deepClone(false) method.  The TaskId has to be changed because the cloned TaskRelations have to be linked to the cloned task.